# Question about かな and だろう

Tags: particles

Among these phrases which is the correct one?

> 今日は雨が降るかな

or

> 今日は雨が降るだろう／でしょう

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. They can mean...

> 今日は雨が降るかな
>   "I wonder if it will rain today." / "Will it rain today?"
>
> 今日は雨が降るだろう／でしょう
>   "It will (probably) rain today." / "I think it will (probably) rain today." / "It will rain today, won't it?"

... depending on intonation and context.